# how to login dashboard with username & password in v1.19.2

Tags: kubernetes, centos, dashboard

i have installed my k8s cluster, and have installed dashboard v2.0.4, and i can login dashboard with token.but how can i login it with username & password ?

please help me!

kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:41:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:32:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

i followed the doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/abac/, and edit the api-servier's config file with

```
- --authorization-mode=RBAC,Node,ABAC
- --authorization-policy-file=/root/dashboard.policy.yaml
```

the dashboard.policy.yaml file content is `{"apiVersion":"abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1","kind":"Policy","spec":{"user":"admin","namespace":"*","resource":"*","apiGroup":"*","nonResourcePath":"*"}}` 
but the api-server cannot start. `telnet 192.168.1.5 6443` cannot connected.

i followed the doc [enter link description here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/)(Bootstrapping clusters with kubeadm), so have no kube-apiserver.service file, i restart my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Basic authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#basic):

> Basic authentication is disabled by default. The reason is that
> Kubernetes API server needs to be configured with authorization mode
> ABAC and `--basic-auth-file` flag provided. Without that API server
> automatically falls back to anonymous user and there is no way to
> check if provided credentials are valid.
>
> In order to enable basic auth in Dashboard `--authentication-mode=basic`
> flag has to be provided. By default it is set to
> `--authentication-mode=token`.

You need to configure Kubernetes to allow basic auth and accept username/password. Here is the [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

After you make sure that you are able to i.e. use `kubectl` configured with username/password to access the cluster, you can enable basic auth for the Dashboard.

Here is a useful [step by step guide](https://techexpert.tips/kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard-user-authentication/) showing how to install the Kubernetes Dashboard and enable the authentication using the username and password.